# ArrayList filtering not working: Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-filter

I have an array list that displays a list of companies. Each of these companies is having town names related to it. What I have done is that I am creating buttons for each of the town names such that when I click on any of the town names, the ArrayList should be filtered and only the companies with that town names should be displayed.

I am creating buttons like,

```
        stringList.add(tempList.get(n).getTownName());
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 60));
        btnTag.setText(stringList.get(k));
        btnTag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alpha_button_selector);
        btnTag.setClickable(true);
        townLayout.addView(btnTag);
```

On clicking the button I am calling the method to filter the data,

```
        btnTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                locationFilter(stringList,length);
            }
        });
```

For filtering the data, I am creating a new ArrayList to store the filtered data such as,

```
        ArrayList<CompanySearchResult> secondList = new ArrayList<CompanySearchResult>();

        for (CompanySearchResult a : tempList) {
            for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {

                if (a.getTownName.equalsIgnoreCase(stringList.get(k))) {
                    secondList.add(a);
                }
            }
        }

        tempList.clear();
        tempList.addAll(secondList);
```

What I am actually trying to do is filtering the temp list according to the town names when the button is clicked.

I have researched on this but could not fix the issue. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I filter the list.

Comment: Which list of yours actually populates the listview? TempList or any other list?

Comment: tempList populates the view.

Comment: then after doing addAll have you called notifyDataSetChanged() method?

Comment: Yes I have called that.

Comment: Any help on what maybe the issue?

Comment: Have you checked if you have filtered it correctly. can you print your tempList before notifydataset and check

Comment: On logging the tempList I am getting something like CompanySearchResult@ada6a87:log. I am not quite sure what is it. Please bear with me I am new to android,

Comment: ok so does it go in your if condition if (a.getTownName.equalsIgnoreCase(stringList.get(k))) {

Comment: Can you print townname there. to mee things seem wrong somewhere and i am not sure

Comment: Yes, it goes to the if condition and I am getting the town names on logging them.

Comment: Ok so then your logged result is correctly filtered result but your listview doesn't update correctly? or your listview doesn't update at all?

Comment: The list view is getting updated but not with the filtered results.

Comment: Then its changing somewhere in between. So Would need more of the code to understand the issue. Or you can put debug pointers to see where your code is going

Comment: okay, thanks for your help... I will check it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was since the buttons were getting created programmatically based on the number of town names(duplicates eliminated), the stringList.get(k), was not giving me the town name correctly corresponding to the button clicked.

Thus, on clicking the button, I fetched the text in the button as it displays the town name and then passed that to the method to filter the data,

```
    btnTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CharSequence name = btnTag.getText();
            locationFilter(name);
        }
    });
```

In my filter method, I changed to,

```
        ArrayList<ACompanyForSearchResult> filtered = new ArrayList<ACompanyForSearchResult>();

        for (ACompanyForSearchResult town : tempList) {

            if (town.getTownName().equals(name)) {
                filtered.add(town);
            }
        }

        tempList.clear();
        tempList.addAll(filtered);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```